# Can rdiff-backup delete increments between backups, *not* the oldest ones?

Tags: backup, rdiff-backup

With backup software I'm used to having an option like "only keep weekly snapshots older than a year, then only keep monthly snapshots older than two years". Basically, save space by deleting intermediate snapshots once they get old enough.

I'm looking into switching to rdiff-backup, but I haven't been able to find an option like that. All I see is people talking about `--remove-older-than`. But I definitely want to keep my oldest snapshot forever. It's just the intermediate ones I can do without!

Is this possible with rdiff-backup, or once I run out of space am I forced to delete my oldest increments?

Answer (score 0):

1. Regular Backups:
   Run regular rdiff-backup commands to create your daily or weekly backups.
2. Retention Policy:
   Use the --remove-older-than option to remove backups that exceed a certain age. However, be careful not to remove the oldest snapshot that you want to keep forever.

***rdiff-backup --remove-older-than 1Y /path/to/backup**

This command will remove backups older than 1 year. Adjust the time frame based on your needs.

3. Periodic Full Backups:
   Periodically, perform full backups to refresh the set of incrementals. This ensures that you have a complete backup set even after removing older increments.

**rdiff-backup --force /path/to/source /path/to/backup**

4. Automate the Process:
   Set up a scheduled job or a cron job to execute the --remove-older-than and periodic full backup commands. This ensures that your retention policy is consistently applied.

**0 2 * * * rdiff-backup --remove-older-than 1Y /path/to/backup
0 3 * * * rdiff-backup --force /path/to/source /path/to/backup**

Adjust the schedule to meet your backup frequency and retention requirements.

By following these numbered steps, you should be able to implement a retention policy with rdiff-backup that keeps the oldest snapshots indefinitely while cleaning up intermediate ones based on your specified time frame.

Comment: I don't understand. This doesn't seem to address my question. I said I wanted to keep my oldest backup and only delete certain snapshots, but this says it removes backups older than 1 year.